# Winform Recursive loop - Method is called again and again

Tags: c#, winforms

Please feel free to create a windows form application. To reproduce the error disable the network connection and run the code. It tries to reconnect after every 1 sec. After 4-5 attempts enable the network connection and in debug mode you will notice that the Reconnect() method is called 4-5 times even the products are fetched. Once the products are fetched why does it call Reconnect() method again and again?

```
        string apiUrl = "https://api.gdax.com/products";
        string json;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            try
            {                
                if (FillProducts()) // product need first
                {
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ReconnectOnError(ex);
            }
        }
        private bool FillProducts()
        {
            bool isDone = false;
            try
            {
                json = GetGDXJSONData(apiUrl);
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(System.Data.DataTable)));

                count = dt.Rows.Count;

                if (count > 0)
                    isDone = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                isDone = false;
                ReconnectOnError(ex);
            }
            return isDone;
        }

        int count = 0;
        private void ReconnectOnError(Exception errorMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (count < 1)
                {
                    FillProducts();     // it comes on this point again and again even the count is greater than 1
                    Reconnect();
                }
                else
                {
                    Reconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ReconnectOnError(ex);
            }
        }

        private void Reconnect()
        {
            // why this is called the number of times the attempt was made to fill the products?
        }      

        private string GetGDXJSONData(string apiUrl)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "gdax-node-client";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Edit - This is a sample code and I am doing lot of things in the Reconnect() method once the products are fetched. 
Also if the error occurs after the products are fetched then don't get the products and simply call the Reconnect() method and that's the reason of else.

Edit2 - Please don't reply just by seeing the code. If you have created a form and run it yourself and can see the error yourself then please advise how to fix this problem.

**Update** - I know I got into a infinite iteration. I tried this and now it works :

```
    string apiUrl = "https://api.gdax.com/products";
    string json;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FillProducts()) // product need first
        {
        }
    }

    bool isOk = false;
    private string GetGDAXProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            json = GetGDXJSONData(apiUrl);
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            return "-1";
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    private bool FillProducts()
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        string retVal = GetGDAXProducts();

        while (retVal == "-1")
        {
            retVal = GetGDAXProducts();
        }

        if (retVal != "-1")
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(System.Data.DataTable)));

            count = dt.Rows.Count;

            if (count > 0)
                isDone = true;
        }

        return isDone;
    }

    private string GetGDXJSONData(string apiUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "gdax-node-client";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
```

Comment: Its due to else part in `if (count < 0)`

Comment: you call it after fillproducts again...

Comment: I have to do that.. It is not coming on that line though. If you run the code you will see it calls FillProducts(); Reconnect(); again and again i.e. the number of times it attempted to reconnect first time when there was no internet

Comment: You have an indirectly recursive call - `FillProducts()` calls `ReconnectOnError(ex);` if there's an exception, which calls `FillProducts()`.

Comment: Please run the code and debug it without internet and then start the internet after 4-5 attempts to reconnect has been made. Please don't stop the application

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                isDone = false;
                ReconnectOnError(ex);
            }` -> output the exception's stacktrace ... you'll see it growing, playing "ping pong" between `ReconnectOnError` and `FillProducts`.

Comment: "Edit - I know I am into a recursive loop." - I added a proposal to avoid the loop in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's cause if there is no network connection then calling the API url fails to  connect and in your `catch` block you are trying to reconnect

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            isDone = false;
            ReconnectOnError(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to reconnect but my problem is once the internet is resumed why it still call 4-5 times the Reconnect() method?

Answer (score 1):

You have an unintentional loop here:

If `FillProducts` fails, it will call itself ...

1. Iteration : FP fails
2. Iteration : FP calls ReconnectOnEx calls FP, which fails again
3. Iteration : FP calls ReconnectOnEx calls FP calls ReconnectOnEx ...

n. Iteration : .... calls FP which succeds **and returns**.

Now the whole stack will unroll with each iteration calling `Reconnect`.

```
private bool FillProducts()
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        try
        {
            /* ... Fails if no connection ... */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            isDone = false;
            ReconnectOnError(ex); // ==> BLOCKS !!
        }
        return isDone;
    }

    int count = 0;
    private void ReconnectOnError(Exception errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (count < 1)
            {
                FillProducts();     // <== Will result in another call to this method. Returns on 1st Succeeding call to FillProducts.
                Reconnect();        // <== Will be called as soon as FillProducts returns.
            }
            else
            {
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            ReconnectOnError(ex);
        }
    }
```

To avoid that, you can move the "retry" logic into the FillProducts method:

```
private bool FillProducts()
    {
        // To prevent waiting forever ...
        int retryCount = 10;

        bool isDone = false;
        while ( !isDone && (retryCount-- > 0) )
        {
            try
            {
                /* ... Fails if no connection ... */

                // OnSuccess=>
                isDone = true; // will break the loop.
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // You should actually catch a more specific Exception here
                                 // ... but that's a different question.
            {               
                isDone = false;
                // Just omit this! >>> ReconnectOnError(ex); // ==> BLOCKS !!
                // If you want, you can add a little delay here ...
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                // From your code, I guess this has to be called on failure ...
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
        return isDone;
    }
```

A few other points to be taken into account:

1. You shouldn't be doing network I/O on the GUI thread. Your GUI may become unresponsive. Consider using async/await (Task Async Pattern)
2. Catching `Exception` is probably not the best idea. You should be catching the most specific Exception possible and have the rest fall through to be handled by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When no internet connection.Count variable coming zero always.

Comment: Please click on "enter image description here" link